# sql query to find the duplicate records

Tags: sql, duplicates

what is the sql query to find the duplicate records and display in descending, based on the highest count and the id display the records.

for example:

getting the count can be done with

```
select title, count(title) as cnt from kmovies group by title order by cnt desc
```

and the result will be like

```
title cnt

ravi   10
prabhu  9
srinu   6
```

now what is the query to get the result like below:

```
ravi
ravi
ravi
...10 times
prabhu
prabhu..9 times
srinu
srinu...6 times
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports the OVER clause...

```
SELECT
   title
FROM
    (
    select
       title, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY title) as cnt
    from
      kmovies
    ) T
ORDER BY
   cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in a single query:

```
Select t.Id, t.title, z.dupCount
From yourtable T
Join
   (select title, Count (*) dupCount
    from yourtable 
    group By title
    Having Count(*) > 1) z
   On z.title = t.Title
order By dupCount Desc
```

Answer (score 5):

This query uses the `Group By` and and `Having` clauses to allow you to select (locate and list out) for each duplicate record. The `As` clause is a convenience to refer to `Quantity` in the `select` and `Order By` clauses, but is not really part of getting you the duplicate rows.

```
Select
    Title,
    Count( Title ) As [Quantity]
   From
    Training
   Group By
    Title
   Having 
    Count( Title ) > 1
   Order By
    Quantity desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct title, (
               select count(title) 
               from kmovies as sub 
               where sub.title=kmovies.title) as cnt 
from kmovies 
group by title 
order by cnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it as a simple single query, but this would do:

```
select title
from kmovies
where title in (
    select title
    from kmovies
    group by title
    order by cnt desc
    having count(title) > 1
)
```

Comment: This won't give correct results because does not repeat rows in COUNT(*) order descending. This is no *outermost* ORDER BY so order is arbritrary. And there are 2 other answers with a single query solution