# SQL working select with group by - how to get the id of found records?

Tags: sql, group-by

Following SQL statements brings the needed records out of the database. In addition I would like to get the id's of those "grouped" records. How can I combine this query with another one to get the needed id's?

My table contains facilities with a lat and lng, some of them are at the same location. I get them by querying as following:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM facilities 
GROUP BY lat, lng having count(*) > 1
```

How can I get facilities.id of those records?

Comment: If you are looking for duplicates (and it sounds like you are) this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779607/sql-query-to-find-the-duplicate-records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your grouped query (slightly modified), to get the `lat` and `lng` you're interested in, and then join those results back to the `facilities` table to get the other data - `id` in this case..

Something like:

```
SELECT a.lat, a.lng, a.locationCount, b.id
FROM (SELECT lat, lng, count(*) locationCount
      FROM facilities 
      GROUP BY lat, lng 
      HAVING count(*) > 1) a
INNER JOIN facilities b on a.lat = b.lat and a.lng = b.lng
```

Comment: Thank you. Works exactly as needed!